# Cumulative Sum from value of two columns starting from second row MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the cumulative sum of column sales and growth starting from second row.

Sample data:

```
select 1 AS SN,'16000' AS Sales,'0' AS Growth,'16000' AS RequiredTotal
INTO #tempa
union select 2,'','500','16500'
union select 3,'','500','17000'
union select 4,'','500','17500'
union select 5,'','500','18000'
union select 6,'','500','18500'
union select 7,'','500','19000'

SELECT * 
FROM #tempa
```

Here I need to get the requiredtotal column.
First value is the sales itself, And starting from second row, need to get the sum of 1st value of requiredtotal column and the growth column second row.

Comment: Any reason you have used single quote for the numbers like sales and grwoth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select a.*,
       (max(sales) over () +
        sum(growth) over (order by sn)
       ) as required
from #tempa a;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d91abcbd9dfe7c4acebcb1eb362e98e) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that I changed the data types in the fiddle so the numbers are actually numbers.  Don't store numbers as strings.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I only posted a sample data query so that it would be easier to create a temp table. The actual data for sales and growth is Money data type on my end.